# Laravel email verification "invalid signature"

Tags: laravel, laravel-mail

Trying to validate user emails and I'm using laravel's default verification system.

It works on local successfully but on live, it return "invalid signature" error.

I'm using AWS

APP_URL is as same as my own domain (https://test.blabla.com)

And don't know what should I tell more.

My AppServiceProvider:

```
public function boot(\Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory $factory)
{
    $factory->composer('*', 'App\Http\View\Composers\AuthenticatedComposer');
    if (env('APP_ENV') === 'production') {
        \URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
```

My routes:

```
Route::get('/email/verify', function () {
    return view('auth_.verify');
})->middleware('auth')->name('verification.notice');

Route::get('/email/verify/{id}/{hash}', function (EmailVerificationRequest $request) {
    $request->fulfill();

    return redirect('/users/emailverified');
})->middleware(['auth', 'signed'])->name('verification.verify');

Route::post('/email/verification-notification', function (Request $request) {
    $request->user()->sendEmailVerificationNotification();

    return back()->with('message', 'Veritification url send!');
})->middleware(['auth', 'throttle:6,1'])->name('verification.resend');
```

Comment: Can you please share your code here?

Comment: I added codes above